# Tkinter invalid command name ".!button"

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run my tkinter code, I run into this error:

```
File "/Users/owen/PycharmProjects/Tutorials/Make7.py", line 147, in user_turn
    btn.config(command=partial(self.tile_prep, btn_n))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1637, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1627, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!button"
```

The line that causes the error is this:

```
btn.config(command=partial(self.tile_prep, btn_n))
```

I'm not sure what's causing the error. Originally, I used

```
btn['command'] = partial(self.tile_prep, btn_n)
```

I tried changing to `.config()`, but this didn't work.
I'm not sure if it's a problem with `partial`. If so, is there another way to pass arguments into button commands? In this case, `btn_n` simply points to the button that was pressed.

Edit: I can't seem to reproduce the problem without including the entire code. Also, the error is very weird: I'm making a connect-4 program, and the error only occurs when the middle three squares in the bottom row are filled. I've looked through the code, and the inner workings seem to be working right, just the GUI component.

Edit 2: I was able to fix the issue by using `.bind()` instead of using the `command` argument. I'm still curious why this issue occurred, though.

Comment: Make sure your button didn't destroyed.

Comment: This is probably telling you that `btn` has been destroyed. Once a button has been destroyed, you can no longer configure it. Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem without including my entire code.

Comment: Also, the button is certainly not destroyed because it can be printed, and if I use lambda instead of partial it works.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling multiple values in a button.So you have to intrigate it on a single function
Such as

```py
btn.config(command=lambda:[self.funcA(x, y)])
```

Try this it may solve your problem

Comment: Do you know what the `partial()` is?  OP just wants to pass `btn_n` to `self.tile_prep()` function.

Comment: This actually works, except for the fact that if I change an argument I want to pass to `self.tile_prep()` later in the code, the function runs with the updated version of the argument. Is there a way around this?